# Does printf consume stack frame in C?

Tags: c, stack, printf

Suppose we  created a user function **void func()**.
The stack frame for **func** is  allocated by function call whenever it is called in some other function such as **main**.

Is it same as **printf** ?
Does  **printf** also consume stack frame?

Comment: A function call is a function call is a function call... All function calls requires a stack-frame (if that's what the implementation uses). Doesn't matter if it's your own functions, standard C function, operating system specific functions or functions from a third-party library.

Comment: The C standard does not require a stack. And some implementations which support a stack don't necessarily use it for all function calls.

Comment: But there are C calling conventions for the different platforms, so this question is perfectly legit (although the OP should have specified the platform for which he is asking, probably x86_64)

Comment: @Ctx It still was too broad, because of optimisations, the actual implementation of `printf` (could be a macro/wrapper, etc.

Comment: @Ctx specific to `printf`, it can use some thread local static storage instead of a stack frame because there are no calls to `printf` from `printf`.

Comment: On the Intel based machine X86 each function-call uses some stack space. The same is for ISR routines. There are the CPU instructions  `CALL` and `INT nn` that uses stack to save the caller-return address (and the flag - INT). The called functions may use or not use stack space, but it's usual they use stack space. Obviously the used stack space should be released at the end of the functions.

Comment: My guess is we have a misunderstanding here: A *stack frame* allocated by a called function (for local variables etc.) and *parameters handed over on the stack* by the calling function are close, but two different things.

Comment: Each function may use a stack frame or not; the behavior should be compiler dependent or user dependent (some compiler may accept the user indicates the stack usage). In most cases of use, on the X86 platforms, each function uses stack frames.

Comment: You say: "The stack frame for func is allocated by function call whenever it is called". The stack frame is not allocated by the function call, it's allocated by the called function when it starts.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini but even if there is a call in the source code, there might not actually be a call instruction generated even in X86 [_64]. It could also be a jmp instruction. In this case no space is consumed even for the return address. So it safe to say, the answer is very implementation and situation specific.

Comment: Obviously, if you use a jmp there's not stack usage by means the jump instrucion (it doesn't save the return address), but the function implementation might manage some stack space. This is the most used behaviour!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Premise: stack frames are just an implementation detail of many C implementations (specifically, it's usually employed on x86); it's neither something that the C standard requires (the C standard doesn't know a thing about the stack), nor something that all implementations do (not even that, it may even depend from compiler flags/optimizer considerations).

Now, of course library functions ultimately are just regular functions that are already compiled into the standard library, so there's nothing special in this regard: in an implementation that employs stack frames, whenever a function call is performed, the called function sets up its stack frame (unless it's inlined or it's completely trivial, but that usually doesn't happen for library function like `printf`).

Still, it's nothing to worry about - when the function returns the new stack frame is discarded and its stack space is available again, so it's not like you have to be careful not to call too many functions.

Comment: NMDV, yet the concept of _stack frame_, although useful, is outside the C specification.  _stack frame_ is an implementation detail of some C compilers.  A compiler can solve this issue in alternate ways.  This answer sounds like _stack frame_ is a universal attribute of C coding.

Comment: @chux: given that the question is about stack frames, my reply is about an implementation that employs such a concept (as most "normal" implementations do).

Comment: I suspect that is why folks DV without explanation.  Comment [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626600/does-printf-consume-stack-frame-in-c/44626723?noredirect=1#comment76239386_44626723), and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626600/does-printf-consume-stack-frame-in-c/44626723?noredirect=1#comment76253350_44626723) supplied a possible motive and then I get a replied with debatable points. "Does printf consume stack frame in C?" could answer "not necessarily" and mention possibilities.  OT: most implementations are embedded processors where the SF is often not used.

Comment: @chux: ok, I'll add a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The stack frame for a function is reserved by that function; no other function can know the stack usage needs of another function, of course.

So when you call `func()` from `main()`, the code inside `func()` (sometimes called the "preamble") will reserve the stack space needed by that function.

And yes, this is true for all functions, that includes `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a small code with a `main` that calls a simple function named `func`.

We may compile this c code using `gcc main.c -S main.s`. main.s shall be an assembly output.

In the assembly you may see the CPU-instructions: push, pop, leave, enter. These instructions are the responsible of stack frames management.

If you compile using gcc with other options you might note some stack management differences.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(void);

int func(void)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("%d",i);

    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    return func();
}
```

GCC Compiler Assembly output

```
        .file   "main.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
        .text
        .globl  func
        .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
        cmpl    $99, -4(%rbp)
        jle     .L3
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   func, .-func
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        call    func
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here the objdump output of the function `func` (`objdump main.o -S`). main.o was obtained by: `gcc main.c -o main.o`

```
000000000040052d <func>:
  40052d:   55                      push   %rbp
  40052e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400531:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400535:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  40053c:   eb 18                   jmp    400556 <func+0x29>
  40053e:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400541:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
  400543:   bf f4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005f4,%edi
  400548:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40054d:   e8 be fe ff ff          callq  400410 <printf@plt>
  400552:   83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  400556:   83 7d fc 63             cmpl   $0x63,-0x4(%rbp)
  40055a:   7e e2                   jle    40053e <func+0x11>
  40055c:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40055f:   c9                      leaveq 
  400560:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400561 <main>:
  400561:   55                      push   %rbp
  400562:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400565:   e8 c3 ff ff ff          callq  40052d <func>
  40056a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40056b:   c3                      retq   
  40056c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `movl    $.LC0, %edi` be `movabsq   $.LC0, %rdi` (or `movq $.LC0(%rip), %rdi`) considering your pointers are 64 bits (because X86_64). Can you please clarify what target you are compiling for. This is completely unrelated to the question but got me wondering.

Comment: This is the assembly output of the gcc compiler for an X86_64 (Intel I3) CPU in a Linux environment where the external (and standard) functions are called loading dynamic libraries.

Comment: If you need to understand where and how the functions use stack, you must look at the piece of code relevant to the `func` function.

Comment: I added other info into my answer. This info was obtained using objdump. I think should be more clear. If you want understand the use of the stack (also into the printf function) you may compile the program using: `gcc -static main.c -o main) and then you have to use `objdump -S main` to generate the assembly dump.

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that printf uses stack frames at least in the X86[_64] Linux/Windows implementation. (We might assume that is the widest behavior)

Comment: I've not the time to indagate why the compiler asm output is `movl $.LCO,%edi`. But I think it's right! Excuse me!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on implementation.  There is no point in all the Standard which requires a tail function call to consume a stack frame, but usually the implementations do consume a frame.

so correct it is to say

> stack frame for func is allocated by function call whenever it is
>   called in some other function such as main
>   `ONLY in some implementations`